# Why this ajax cannot send variables to php?

Tags: php, ajax

Its a very simple process but i can't make it work. i've read a lot of oother posts with similar issues but none of the solutions manage to do it for me.

The js part:

```
echo "<script>

let text = 'Do you wish to continue?'
if (confirm(text) == true){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'SQL.php',
        data: { continuar:'OK' },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>";
```

The php part:

```
var_dump(json_encode($_POST));
var_dump($_REQUEST);
if (isset($_REQUEST['continuar']) && $_REQUEST['continuar'] == 'OK'){
    var_dump($_REQUEST['continuar']);
    echo"<br> <br> <br> <br>";
}
```

Now, the alert actually pops up in the page with a bunch of html but not with my variable.
If you guys need any more info i will be pleased to provide.

Comment: What's the HTML that comes up, linebreaks? Why even have that JS in the PHP block?

Comment: Don't you need a semicolon on the 1st line? You're saying that your issue is that the XHR is not being sent, have you checked your browser's network tab under the dev tools? Also, are you seeing any errors in the console of your browser? Learning how to check these error codes will help you in troubleshooting any problem moving forward.

Comment: That "bunch of html" will tell you whats wrong.

Comment: the js in php block is not my personal choice, i simply have to patch like that. But focusing on the question, i cannot copy the html in the pop-up but it just prints the html of the page sql.php

Comment: that html is the response you are getting from the server; and the server could be sending you some error page and since you are echoing it in an alert; it just shows the naked html. You need to read the html.

Comment: guys guys, my first time using ajax.  i only used this way to debug via alert because i saw it in other answers. now if there is a better way, via console, please share

Comment: i ve only just said the html it shows is the source code of the page

Comment: also i put the semicolon on the 1st line but the problem persists

Comment: try `console.log(data)` and if you can't understand what the html says; try adding the html to your post above.

Comment: ok. i tried to console.log(data) but it shows nothin on the console. i can't see the full html like u pointed out @Chin.Udara

Comment: Try adding dataType: "json", inside of your ajax

Comment: it gives back two issues. the first: One or more documents in this page is in Quirks Mode, which will render the affected document(s) with quirks incompatible with the current HTML and CSS specifications.
Quirks Mode exists mostly due to historical reasons. If this is not intentional, you can add or modify the DOCTYPE to be `<!DOCTYPE html>` to render the page in No Quirks Mode.

Comment: the second: A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.

Comment: after i tried the json datatype

Comment: @Yeak that suggestion does not make sense. The php code clearly does not return JSON.